# Copy pasting columns from one sheet to rows of another sheet with different count up steps in the for loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have one sheet: 'trainingmatrix' with information in row 2 columns B,D,F,H ...
which I would like to paste into another sheet 'vlearning' column C, rows 2,3,4,5.... I have tried the code below but it does not seem to work ...any ideas ? There should be a problem with the for loop but it's my first time doing a for loop with two variables and different count up steps.

````
  var trainingmatrix=ss.getSheetByName('Training Matrix');
  var vlearning=ss.getSheetByName('VLearning_Upload');

var lr=getlastrow(trainingmatrix,"A1:HA");

var tnavalues=trainingmatrix.getRange(1,1,lr-1,15).getValues();

var vlearnvalues=vlearning.getRange(1,1,vlearning.getLastRow(),
vlearning.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for (var i=1 &&  j=1;i<vlearnvalues.length && j<vlearnvalues[0].length;i++ && j=j+2){


     vlearnvalues[i][2]=tnavalues[1][j];

    }



  Logger.log(values);```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try looping with your two variables with two nested 'for' loops.

```
for (var i = 1; i < vlearnvalues.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j < vlearnvalues[0].length; j++) {
    vlearnvalues[i][2] = tnavalues[1][j];
  }
}
```

Although I would make sure your variables (vlearnvalues, tnavalues) contain what you think they do by logging them before looping over them because I'm not sure you're going to achieve what you want even with this loop working correctly.

Comment: But I still get the same problem: the only cell that is copy pasted from tnavalues is the one from the highest value of variable j

Comment: @Cooper https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CSQEOc1dKS1bG4Uuok0dkcPsku2LSRyePn20D_yoqNM/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

I can see several issues in your code:

1. You have the wrong syntax for finding the last row. Please replace `var lr=getlastrow(trainingmatrix,"A1:HA");`through   `var lr = trainingmatrix.getLastRow();`
2. As camaulay pointed out, you can not iterate over i and j simultaneously in one for loop, but rather have to nest the “j” loop inside the “i” loop.
3. Think about what you are doing: you are taking `vlearnvalues[0].length` (which is 15) and try to access the value  `tnavalues[1][j]`, which might not exist if the range width in `Training Matrix` is narrower than in `VLearning_Upload`.
4. Unfortunately `vlearnvalues[i][2]=tnavalues[1][j];` does not work in Apps Script. Instead you need to access an individual cell within your range `VLearning_Upload` and use the function `setValue()` to assign it a value from the range in  `Training Matrix`.
5. How do you choose that only certain values from the sheet `Training Matrix` are supposed to be copied? You need an if statement for it. E.g., assuming that B,D,F,H are  non empty columns - and you want to copy only the non-empty values, you could implement: `if(tnavalues[1][j]!="")`.

A sample code which meets your requirements would be this:

```
function Copy() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var trainingmatrix=ss.getSheetByName('Training Matrix');
  var vlearning=ss.getSheetByName('VLearning_Upload');
  var lr = trainingmatrix.getLastRow();  
  var tnavalues=trainingmatrix.getRange(1,1,lr-1,15).getValues();
  var vlearnvalues=vlearning.getRange(2,3,vlearning.getLastRow(),vlearning.getLastColumn());
  var array=[];
  for (var j=1; j<tnavalues[0].length; j++)
  {
    if(tnavalues[1][j]!="")
    {
      array.push(tnavalues[1][j])
    }
  }
  for(var i=1;i<vlearnvalues.getHeight();i++)
  {
    var cell=vlearnvalues.getCell(i,1);              
    if(typeof array[(i-1)]!=='undefined')
    {
      cell.setValue(array[(i-1)]); 
    }
  }
}
```

Please refer to the Apps Script reference to find more information about different methods and examples of how to use them:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka. Thank you for these valuable tips :) Also for point number 2. For point number 1, I am calling a function which gets me the last row with data. Now I tried to implement your code, but I still get nothing :/

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CSQEOc1dKS1bG4Uuok0dkcPsku2LSRyePn20D_yoqNM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Cooper here is a copy of my sheet. I am basically trying to move whats highlighted in the Traininx Matrix sheet into whats highlighted in the VLearning_Upload sheet ...

Comment: So I would have in the VLearning_Upload sheet cell C2: 'Daniel Tan', cell C3:'Pierre Mahe', etc ...

Comment: The problem might be that all your rows apart from row 1 are empty, so vlearning.getLastRow() will be 1, which is smaller than the initial row 2... I suggest you to substitute vlearning.getLastRow() through a manually chosen last row which is suitable for your application - I assume it would be 12.And as for the columns, you actually only use the column C. So you could use the method: 
getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns). In your case: var vlearnvalues=vlearning.getRange(2,3,11,1);

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and some values do get copied. The problem is, it is always the same value which gets copied which is the last non empty value from the sheet I am trying to copy values from ...

Comment: here is the piece of code I tried with your suggestions:

Comment: ```var tnavalues=trainingmatrix.getRange(1,1,20,15).getValues();
  //Logger.log(tnavalues);
  
  var vlearnvalues=vlearning.getRange(2,3,15,1);
  
 for(var i=2;i<15;i++) {
    for (var j=1; j<15; j++) {
     var cell=vlearnvalues.getCell(i,1); 
    if(tnavalues[1][j]!="") {
       cell.setValue(tnavalues[1][j]);
     }
    }
  }```

Comment: Please try this: `var vlearnvalues=vlearning.getRange(2,3,15,1); 
for(var i=1;i<15;i++) 
{
  var cell=vlearnvalues.getCell(i,1); 
  Logger.log(cell.getA1Notation())
             
  if(typeof array[(i-1)]!=='undefined')
  {
      cell.setValue(array[(i-1)]); 
  }
}`  I updated the answer